# Access Variable value in Mapper File of mybatis

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am using Spring and Mybatis in my project . Project can run in any platform like SQL Server Oracle etc.

I am facing 1 Problem i want to access variable value From properties file,application Context file to Mybatis Mapper file.

For.eg : 
ApplicationContext.xml  - Spring file 
config.properties file

in above file want to decalare variable lets say 
pName = XYZ

i want to access this pName in Mybatis Mapper XML file.

```
<select id="getValue" parameterType="java.lang.String" >
${pName}
</select>
```

How is it possible ?if have any other solution most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access spring way :
Use

```
<util:properties id="myPropertyConfigurer" location="classpath:yourpropertiesfile.properties"/>

<context:property-placeholder  properties-ref="myPropertyConfigurer" order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="applicationDataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:sqlMapConfig.xml" />
    <property name="configurationProperties" ref="myPropertyConfigurer"></property>
</bean>
```

In your mapper xml file :

```
<select id="searchSomeOne" parameterType="map" .....>
        SELECT
        ${pName} AS module
        FROM MY_TABLE
        WHERE
        COL_ONE = #{moduleName} and
        COL_TWO like #{username}
</select>
```

and define `pName=MODULE` in the yourpropertiesfile.properties

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way - 
1. Add the below line of code in your `mybatis-config.xml` file

```
<properties resource="path/to/config.properties" />
```

Then you should be able access all the keys as `${keyName}` in the mapper file .

Reference from the mybatis docs - http://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#properties

Comment: I am not using mybatis-config.xml file ,i am using Spring [applicationcontext.xml file].